# Python: Elegantly print all *remaining* elements from list in one line

Tags: python

I'm looking for the most correct way to print a list of elements after replacing one of them. I could do as follows but it's obviously messy.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1])

for line in file:
    cols = line.split('\t')

    if(float(cols[2]) > 97):
        print line
    else:
        print cols[0] + "\tNo_Match\t" + cols[2] + "\t" + cols[3] + "\t" + cols[4] + "\t" + .....  + "\t" +cols[20]
```

EDIT: I just realised it would be even worse because I missed out the  + "\t"

Comment: Could you please be clearer about what you expect? For instance, will the match condition be always `float(cols[2]) > 97`?

Comment: cols[2] will always be a % score of how well the input has matched the database. I have hardcoded '97' here just as an example but in the end the user will be able to specify on run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `join` method of a string to print your list:

```
cols[1] = "No_Match"
print '\t'.join(cols)
```

This will print off all entries of cols separated by a '\t'.

Notice how I replaced the element 1 of cols first.  If you don't want to do that, you can do either

```
print '\t'.join(cols[0:1]+['No_Match']+cols[2:])
```

or

```
print '\t'.join([x if i != 1 else 'No_Match' for i, x in enumerate(cols)])
```

Comment: I implemented @senshin's as it came up first, then read yours and realised it's much simpler if I replace the field, making the whole code only 7 lines long now. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted because I think it's the most 'Pythonically' correct.

Answer (score 4):

This gives identical behavior to the last line of your code:

```
print cols[0] + "\tNo_match\t" + ''.join(cols[2:])
```

To match the revised version of your code:

```
print cols[0] + "\tNo_match\t" + '\t'.join(cols[2:])
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you very much. I'm still learning and forcing myself to write python instead of perl and sometimes come stuck!